# Using gb4e with amsbook class

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, amsbook

I am required to use *amsbook* for a project, but I find that it messed up the alignment of interlinear glosses with the *gb4e* package.
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{gb4e} 

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex 
    \gll nya te ma\\
    small one PL\\
    \glt `little ones'\\
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Misaligned gloss]

The third line should be left-aligned with the first two lines. How can I fix this without ruining indentation in other places in the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `amsbook` class wants to keep the value of `\parindent` inside lists, so it sets `\listparindent` to `\normalparindent`. Set this one to zero inside `exe`, because `exe` expects `\listparindent` to be zero.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\AddToHook{env/exe/begin}{\setlength{\normalparindent}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex
    \gll nya te ma\\
    small one PL\\
    \glt `little ones'
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't want `\\` at the end.